# Angular2 component based on canvas : how to draw inside?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I wrote a simple component based on a canvas, which I am resizing with an Input() property inside the companion class (TypeScript code). What I would like to do is to draw the canvas element inside the companion class, whose code is below : what is the simplest way to achieve that ? (Please, see the comment in the code : I would like to draw a blue rectangle inside the canvas from the constructor).

```
import {Component, View, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'chess-diagram',
})
@View({
    template: `<canvas class='chess-diag'
     [attr.width]='_size'
     [attr.height]='_size'></canvas>`,
})
export class ChessDiagram {
    private _size: number;

    constructor(){
        this._size = 150;
        // Here I would like to draw a blue rectangle inside the canvas.
    }

    get size(){
        return this._size;
    }

    @Input () set size(newValue: number){
        this._size = Math.floor(newValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the **ViewChild** annotation to grab an instance of your canvas element. After that it's all vanilla js.

```js
import {Component, View, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'chess-diagram',
})
@View({
    template: `<canvas #chessCanvas class='chess-diag'
     [attr.width]='_size'
     [attr.height]='_size'></canvas>`,
})
export class ChessDiagram {
    private _size: number;

    // get the element with the #chessCanvas on it
    @ViewChild("chessCanvas") chessCanvas: ElementRef; 

    constructor(){
        this._size = 150;
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() { // wait for the view to init before using the element

      let context: CanvasRenderingContext2D = this.chessCanvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
      // happy drawing from here on
      context.fillStyle = 'blue';
      context.fillRect(10, 10, 150, 150);
    }

    get size(){
        return this._size;
    }

    @Input () set size(newValue: number){
        this._size = Math.floor(newValue);
    }
}
```

The **@ViewChild** will return an **[ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html)** you can obtain the native canvas element from that using the **nativeElement** property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I get the chessCanvas variable as undefined.

Comment: in ngAfterViewInit there might be a typo somewhere. I'll setup a component and check that it works. :)

Comment: Thank you, I am also trying to find it.

Comment: fixed it. As it turns out @ViewChild returns an ElementRef not the element itself. I'll update the question with this info.

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @toskv ,  I wrote a question based on your input in that thread here "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273002/ionic2-angular2-add-graph-component-with-its-own-selector-to-a-page" . On transpiling, it says that "it cannot find name 'ElementRef'" . Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @nyluje this has been quite a long time ago, it might be that the angular api has changed. I will have a look at your question.