# Angular 2 - "Cannot read property 'getContext' of null" error when using HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular, html5-canvas

I'm trying to display a donut chart that's made using HTML5 Canvas. I'm getting an error saying that `Cannot read property 'getContext' of null`, which I know is getting because my JS code is loading before the HTML is loaded.

How do I solve this problem in Angular2?

Working Code (getting error): http://plnkr.co/edit/hYlFp1BX8ebixQMqAtNj?p=preview

Working Donut chart in Html: https://jsfiddle.net/nvarun123/yn1bhj2a/4/

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var colors=['green','orange'];
var values=[47,53];
var labels=['Completed','Pending'];

dmbChart(125,125,100,25,values,colors,labels,0);

function dmbChart(cx,cy,radius,arcwidth,values,colors,labels,selectedValue){
    var tot=0;
    var accum=0;
    var PI=Math.PI;
    var PI2=PI*2;
    var offset=-PI/2;
    ctx.lineWidth=arcwidth;
    for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){tot+=values[i];}
    for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,
            offset+PI2*(accum/tot),
            offset+PI2*((accum+values[i])/tot)
        );
        ctx.strokeStyle=colors[i];
        ctx.stroke();
        accum+=values[i];
    }
    var innerRadius=79;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx,cy,innerRadius,0,PI2);
    ctx.fillStyle=colors[selectedValue];
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.textAlign='center';
    ctx.textBaseline='bottom';
    ctx.fillStyle='white';
    ctx.font=(60)+'px verdana';
    ctx.fillText(values[selectedValue],cx,cy+innerRadius*.7);
    ctx.font=(20)+'px verdana';
    ctx.fillText(labels[selectedValue],cx,cy-innerRadius*.25);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class="cont" width=250 height=250></canvas>
```

If there's a way to solve it please tell me.

Comment: It sounds like you already know the solution.

Comment: But no idea how to implement in Angular 2

Comment: I’m not an expert in AngularJS, but shouldn’t it work the same way in AngularJS? After all, your JavaScript is just that: JavaScript. All solutions should work the same, even with AngularJS, e.g. wrapping your code in `addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){`…`})`, or putting the script at the bottom of the `<body>`.

Comment: What part of this code is from angular? :) btw i succest using react

Comment: I'm trying to implement this as an component in Angular 2. So i need this to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your canvas as follows:

```
 var ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = this.childComponent.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
```

Your component will be:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'canvas-component',
    template: `<canvas #childComponent></canvas>`,
})
export class ParentComponent{
    ...
    @ViewChild childComponent: ElementRef; 
    ...
}
```

More details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36164708/1267942

Answer (score 0):

It's working after i put the code in the class in `ngAfterViewInit() {}`

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector:'test-component',
    styleUrls: ['./test.component.css'],
    templateUrl: './test.component.html'

})
export class TestComponent{


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var colors=['green','orange'];
var values=[47,53];
var labels=['Completed','Pending'];

dmbChart(125,125,100,25,values,colors,labels,0);

function dmbChart(cx,cy,radius,arcwidth,values,colors,labels,selectedValue){
    var tot=0;
    var accum=0;
    var PI=Math.PI;
    var PI2=PI*2;
    var offset=-PI/2;
    ctx.lineWidth=arcwidth;
    for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){tot+=values[i];}
    for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,
            offset+PI2*(accum/tot),
            offset+PI2*((accum+values[i])/tot)
        );
        ctx.strokeStyle=colors[i];
        ctx.stroke();
        accum+=values[i];
    }
    var innerRadius=79;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx,cy,innerRadius,0,PI2);
    ctx.fillStyle=colors[selectedValue];
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.textAlign='center';
    ctx.textBaseline='bottom';
    ctx.fillStyle='#FFF';
    ctx.font=(60)+'px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillText(values[selectedValue],cx,cy+innerRadius*.7);
    ctx.font=(20)+'px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillText(labels[selectedValue],cx,cy-innerRadius*.25);
}
      }

}
```