# ionic2 angular2 add graph component (with its own selector) to a page

Tags: canvas, angular, ionic2

In **Ionic2 / Angular2**: I try to figure out how to add a graph with its **own selector** to a page.

**Starting from the Ionic2 tutorial project I added 2 elements: "MyPage" and "MyGraphDiagram". And I want to use "MyGraphDiagram" in "MyPage".**

In "[MyProject]/src/app/app.module.ts" I have:

```
import ...
import { MyPage } from '../pages/my/my';
import { MyGraphDiagram } from '../pages/my/graph-components/my-graph';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HelloIonicPage,
    ItemDetailsPage,
    ListPage,
    MyPage,
    MyGraphDiagram
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HelloIonicPage,
    ItemDetailsPage,
    ListPage,
    MyPage,
    MyGraphDiagram
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**FIRST**: Here if I compile the project it has a problem with MyGraphDiagram in the declartions node (also I thought I had implemented MyGraphDiagram correctly).

In [MyProject]/src/app/app.component.ts, it stays the same except that the page to root is substitued  with: `rootPage: any=MyPage`.

In "[MyProject]/src/pages/my/graph-components/my-graph.ts" (it is a copy of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163905/angular2-component-based-on-canvas-how-to-draw-inside)):

```
import {Component, View, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-graph',
})
@View({
    template: `<canvas #myGraph class='myGraph'
     [attr.width]='_size'
     [attr.height]='_size'></canvas>`,
})

export class MyGraphDiagram {
    private _size: number;

    // get the element with the #myGraph on it
    @ViewChild("myGraph") myGraph: ElementRef; 

    constructor(){
        this._size = 150;
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() { // wait for the view to init before using the element

      let context: CanvasRenderingContext2D = this.myGraph.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
      // happy drawing from here on
      context.fillStyle = 'blue';
      context.fillRect(10, 10, 150, 150);
    }

    get size(){
        return this._size;
    }

    @Input () set size(newValue: number){
        this._size = Math.floor(newValue);
    }
}
```

Then finally under "[MyProject]/src/pages/my/my.ts":

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MyGraphDiagram } from '/graph-component/my-graph'


@Component({
    selector:'my-page',
    template: 'my.html'
})
export class MyPage {
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams){

    }
}
```

And "[MyProject]/src/pages/my/my.html":

```
<ion-header>...
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <my-graph></my-graph>
</ion-content>
```

**If I run a CLI "ionic run android":**
If I leave MyGraphDiagram in the `declaration` node of "[MyProject]/src/app/app.module.ts", the **lint** part doesn't go thru. it throws an error:

> Error: Unexpected value 'MyGraphDiagram' declared by the module
>   'AppModule'

If I take MyGraphDiagram of the `declartion` node, the lint part goes thru but build throw that error:

> 'my-graph' is not a known element:
>
> [00:08:06]  1. If 'my-graph' is an Angular component, then verify
>   that it is part of this module. [00:08:06]  2. If 'my-graph' is a
>   Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the
>   '@NgModule.schema'

Some update:
**If I run a CLI "ionic serve":**

The TypeScript Transpile fails with this error:

> it cannot find name 'ElementRef'
>   L13: myGraph: ElementRef;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove MyGraphDiagram from entryComponents and leave it on declarations in app.module.ts.

Then, update the MyGraphDiagram component to follow RC1 standard, using an html template and removing the @view part.

Comment: I did: MyGraphDiagramm removed from entry component. Then In "[MyProject]/src/pages/my/graph-components/my-graph.ts" @Component changed  with: @Component({
    selector: 'my-graph',
    templateUrl: 'my-graph.html'
})`
New file: "[MyProject]/src/pages/my/graph-components/my-graph.html" with: `<ion-header>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
<canvas #myGraph class='myGraph'
     [attr.width]='_size'
     [attr.height]='_size'></canvas>
</ion-content>`. When running in CLI Ionic serve and TSC --watch, I still get:  "it cannot find name 'ElementRef'
L13: myGraph: ElementRef;"

Comment: I see. For now, you may remove the type in the view as: `@ViewChild("myGraph") myGraph;`

Comment: i did an npm install (seems to be the magic trick in ionic2) and I get less error messages. It seems also that it has some problem having subfolder withing the folder of a page. The project display but the event  ngAfterViewInit() is not triggered so still noshape visible on the screen.

Comment: Some users have commented that removing Ionic and installing it again solved some type-related issues, specially if the project has been upgraded from previous Ionic versions.

Comment: i ll dig and update my question with my progress. Thanks for the tip. It remembers me with symfony and "clean cache" or "assetic rebuild" if you are familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks for you help the issue is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of ionic do you use? `@view` is deprecated, you can just define you component like:

`` @Component({
    selector: 'my-graph',
    template: `<canvas #myGraph class='myGraph'
     [attr.width]='_size'
     [attr.height]='_size'></canvas>`
  })
  export class MyGraphDiagram {
  ... ``

Comment: In "[MyProject]/src/pages/my/graph-components/my-graph.ts"  I took template inside @Component annotation and took away \\@view annotation (+ from the import statement at the top of the file to make it: "import {Component, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';". I still have the error message: "on build Error: Unexpected value 'MyGraphDiagram' declared by the module 'AppModule'"

Comment: To complete your question I use Ionic 2.1.0.

Comment: Thanks for your help the issue is closed.